# UISegmentedControl can no longer set background color using IOS 13 Objective C

Tags: xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to update my app to IOS 13 to meet the new deadline.

I noticed that I can no longer change the background color of UISegmentedControls

```
scAngle = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:Frame];
[scAngle insertSegmentWithTitle:@"No" atIndex:0 animated:false];
[scAngle insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Yes" atIndex:1 animated:false];
[scAngle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

No matter what color I enter, it just appears as a default light gray background and a slightly darker gray for the selected segment. Its not easy to discern which segment is selected.

It worked fine under previous IOS and xcode.

I would also mention that setting the tint color to any other color also ignored and the title of the button is always black.

Comment: Works for me. Also, the default colors in when running my App with iOS 13 are gray for the background, and white for the selected element.

Comment: How do you change the colors to colors other than default?  I can only get the default colors when using segmented controls.  The code above only renders the default colors.